# Extract / distinguish ActivityAlias name from TargetActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-activity-alias

I have multiple `ActivityAliases` which all start one single `TargetActivity`.
Inside of my `TargetActivity` I try to **distinguish the alias** that started
the `TargetActivity`.

The aliases are defined in `Manifest` as launchables (intent-filter), which will be displayed as 
shortcuts on the homescreen. The user will click on the shortcut and android
will start the activity, which I defined in the "`android:targetActivity=..`" tag.

For that I currently extract the `componentName` from the `Intent`, which is 
given to my TargetActivity and using the `className()`.

Like:

```
String aliasName = targetActivity.getComponentName().getClassName();
```

This works fine for a lot of devices. But currently I see some failures on 
the *OnePlus*. At that device, **my technique only returns the className of 
my TargetActivity** and therefore I can't deliver the action, based on the 
alias that the user started.

Are there any other, **reliable** methods to get `ActivityAlias` that was used to
start the `TargetActivity`? It does not need to be the name itself, as long 
as I can distinguish them. *I do not want to create dedicated TargetActivities for every Alias!*

Thanks!

Ps.: I saw another way, which uses the PackageManager to retrieve the 
activityInfo and using the Activity.name. But I doubt that this will 
return something different than my first approach.

```
ActivityInfo aInfo = activity.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

String aliasName = aInfo.name;
```

**I also tried meta-data:**

**Edit:**

*Unfortunately this method does not work for all devices. 
If the parsed `alias-className` from the activity.component returns the
`target-activity`, then the meta-data approach fails, too.*

I continued searching for an answer and found a good workaround to 
distinguish between my aliases inside of the TargetActivty.

You can provide meta-data within your ActivityAlias tag like so:

```
<activity-alias 
    android:name=".aliasName" 
    android:enabled="false" 
    android:exported="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/someIconRes" 
    android:label="@string/someLabelRes" android:targetActivity=".yourTargetActivity"> 
    <meta-data android:name="alias" android:value="valueToDistinguish"/>
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
</activity-alias>
```

The important part here is:

```
<meta-data android:name="alias" android:value="valueToDistinguish"/>
```

Which is within the `<activity-alias>` here `</activity-alias>` tag.

To extract the meta-data you can get an ActivityInfo from the PackageManager 
with the TargetActivity:

```
ActivityInfo appInfo = activity.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

And extract the meta-data via:

```
    private static String getAliasNameByMetaData(ActivityInfo app) {
    String aliasName = "";
    if (app.metaData != null && app.metaData.containsKey(ALIAS_META_DATA_KEY)) {
        aliasName = app.metaData.getString(ALIAS_META_DATA_KEY, "");
    } else {
        LOG.i("AliasName by META-DATA didn't work!");
    }
    LOG.v("AliasName by META-DATA: " + aliasName);
    return aliasName;
}
```

**Edit:**

Inspecting the `Activity` class using the debugger, it includes a `mActivityInfo` field that is different from the `ActivityInfo` returned by `getPackageManager().getActivityInfo()` so you can extract it using reflection and check it's name.

Note: It seems that the `ActivityInfo` returned by `getPackageManager().getActivityInfo()` is a shallow copy of the `mActivityInfo` from the `Activity`. So, maybe this method does not resolve the issue:

```
Field field = Activity.class.getDeclaredField("mActivityInfo");
field.setAccessible(true);
ActivityInfo value = (ActivityInfo) field.get(this);
Log.e("APPINFO2", "NAME: " + value.name);
```

Comment: how exactly did the meta-data approach fail?

Comment: There were no meta data in the ActivityInfo.

Comment: If you inspect your `targetActivity` on debug, does the `mActivityInfo` field show your Activity or your Alias?

Comment: For me, on my test device, it shows the alias. In the past I used the mActivityInfo.name to distinguish my aliases. But unfortunately in the wild there are devices where mActivityInfo returns the targetActivity.

Comment: It makes no sense that I post an answer that points to use `mActivity` info to retrieve the name then. I'm editing your question to add this method to improve it if you don't mind

Comment: Well, I think I already have this one in the question. But yes, edit the question if you think it improves it. Thank you so far! (edit: reflection - i see)

Comment: JacksOnF1re, did you find a solution? I have similar problem, and I'm currently using activity.getComponentName(). Decided to find possible issues, just in case, and found your question.

Comment: You should answer your own question. This would remove the question from the list of unanswered questions and would also probably help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Meta-Data**

*Unfortunately this method does not work for all devices. 
If the parsed `alias-className` from the activity.component returns the
`target-activity`, then the meta-data approach fails, too.*

I continued searching for an answer and found a good workaround to 
distinguish between my aliases inside of the TargetActivty.

You can provide meta-data within your ActivityAlias tag like so:

```
<activity-alias 
    android:name=".aliasName" 
    android:enabled="false" 
    android:exported="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/someIconRes" 
    android:label="@string/someLabelRes" android:targetActivity=".yourTargetActivity"> 
    <meta-data android:name="alias" android:value="valueToDistinguish"/>
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
</activity-alias>
```

The important part here is:

```
<meta-data android:name="alias" android:value="valueToDistinguish"/>
```

Which is within the `<activity-alias>` here `</activity-alias>` tag.

To extract the meta-data you can get an ActivityInfo from the PackageManager 
with the TargetActivity:

```
ActivityInfo appInfo = activity.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

And extract the meta-data via:

```
    private static String getAliasNameByMetaData(ActivityInfo app) {
    String aliasName = "";
    if (app.metaData != null && app.metaData.containsKey(ALIAS_META_DATA_KEY)) {
        aliasName = app.metaData.getString(ALIAS_META_DATA_KEY, "");
    } else {
        LOG.i("AliasName by META-DATA didn't work!");
    }
    LOG.v("AliasName by META-DATA: " + aliasName);
    return aliasName;
}
```

---

**2. mActivityInfo**

Inspecting the `Activity` class using the debugger, it includes a `mActivityInfo` field that is different from the `ActivityInfo` returned by `getPackageManager().getActivityInfo()` so you can extract it using reflection and check it's name.

Note: It seems that the `ActivityInfo` returned by `getPackageManager().getActivityInfo()` is a shallow copy of the `mActivityInfo` from the `Activity`. So, maybe this method does not resolve the issue:

```
Field field = Activity.class.getDeclaredField("mActivityInfo");
field.setAccessible(true);
ActivityInfo value = (ActivityInfo) field.get(this);
Log.e("APPINFO2", "NAME: " + value.name);
```