# Launch android app with parameters - shortcut

Tags: android

I developed an Android app which read a config file.
Now, I would like load my app with another file config.

In fact, I would like create 2 shortcuts of my app:

- myApp filepathconfig1
- myApp filepathconfig2

Is it possible?
If yes, how get the parameters in my code?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Main question is how you plan to run your app with different configurations? From device Home screen?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it ... like shorcut windows target in home screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy to do on Android 7.1 Nougat API level 25 or higher.

There is a dedicated [Shortcut API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/) that lets you define shortcuts to you activity with specific `Intent` where you can add extras like this:

```
<intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.LAUNCH_WITH_CONFIG"
    android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
    android:targetClass="com.example.myapplication.ComposeActivity" >

    <extra android:name="configFile" android:value="filepathconfig1" />

</intent>
```

The code above is base on an example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#static).

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:**
You can also add and remove shortcuts dynamically as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#dynamic).
You will need some UI in you app to manage the shortcuts if you want to change them as a user, without recompiling.

To access the extra in you code, just do this in you activity class:

```
String configPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("configFile");
```

How ever, if you need to support Android versions before 7.1, it gets more complicated.

There are two options I can think of:
The first one is using [<activity-alias>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745816/extract-distinguish-activityalias-name-from-targetactivity).

Note however that the author of that question states that it is not guaranteed to work on all devices.

Another option is to create two dummy launcher activities that will be invisible and will `finish()` immediately after starting you real main activity with the correct parameter.

This is the ugliest hack in my opinion but also most reliable and universal one for this problem.

In your manifest, set activity theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

In this activity's `onCreate` add code like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, RealMainActivity.class);
i.puStringExtra("configFile", "filepathconfig1");
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

I see from your comment you want this to work dynamically, without recompiling the APK, but Android launchers do not support such a feature.
At least, I never heard of one that does.

It is possible to create such a launcher though.

The only way currently to start you activity with dynamic parameters is from adb:

adb shell am start com.myactivity --es configFile configFilePath

For more details read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am).

Comment: Then you can use the ShortcutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager to dynamically create and delete shortcuts from within you own app.
You can create a shortcut editor in your app then you won't have to recompile it to add path of new file.
Full explanation on how to manage shortcuts dynamically is in the link in my answer.

Comment: OK I look a sample [here](https://medium.com/@andreworobator/implementing-android-app-shortcuts-74feb524959b)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here :

1. Use shortcuts https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/
2. If you want two different icons. Define two main launch activities like below and define your config files in the activities.

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="your.package.Activity1"
       android:label="Activity1">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <activity
       android:name="your.package.Activity2"
       android:label="Activity 2">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

Comment: Option 2 : but it's in the code and not dynamic. If I want add a third config I have to recompilated and I don't want...

Comment: what are you trying to build. how do you want to provide the config dynamically

Comment: I want build apk, install apk, create 2 to n differents shorcuts and my app read a different config every time ... perhaps it's not possible ...